# Is there an event that fires when a user select an autocomplete value?

Tags: javascript, html

If I have a form with an autocomplete field:

```
<form>
    <label>First name: <input type=text autocomplete="given-name"></label>
</form>
```

is there an event that fires when the user selects an autocomplete value from the dropdown (but before the blur event)?

Comment: `oninput`? Or did you want something *specifically* for autocomplete detection?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol do'h. Thanks :-)

Comment: `onchange` will also fire when you select an autocomplete option. It won't call the blur event until you deselect the input.

Answer (score 1):

You could try getting the background color by using `window.getComputedStyle(elem).getPropertyValue("background-color")`, although this only works in Chrome (as far as I know, it's the only browser that changes input background color on autocomplete).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function getBgrColor(elem) {
    return window.getComputedStyle(elem).getPropertyValue("background-color");
  }
  var initial = getBgrColor($('input')[0]);
  $('input').on('blur input', function() {
    var bgr = getBgrColor($(this)[0]);
    if (bgr != initial) {
      console.log("Autofilled");
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  Select an autocomplete option, then click outside the input
  <br><br>
  <label>First name: <input type=text name="name"
            autocomplete="given-name"></label>
</form>
```

Demo in Chrome:

[image: Chrome Autofill Demo]

Comment: I'm not sure what the background color has to do with this question..?

Comment: @thebjorn Autocomplete in Chrome causes the background to change color. You can utilize this to detect autocomplete.

Comment: lolz. Not what I was asking about (I'm guessing it is the blur event that detects the color change), but a weird and hacky solution. I give you a point :-)